# What is the best way to generate video thumbnails?

Tags: django, vue.js, amazon-s3, thumbnails, video-thumbnails

I am creating an application with Vue.js and Django.
I am getting a list of videos from AWS S3 and I am displaying it in the frontend. Now I need to create thumbnails for these videos?
I want to know what is the best practice to generate the thumbnails?
Should I:

1. Should I generate thumbnails on the frontend side each time it receives videos?
2. Should I generate thumbnails on the backend side each time videos are requested?
3. Should I generate thumbnails on the backend and save them in the storage and then send them when the videos are requested?

Currently, I am finding solutions on how to generate thumbnails on the frontend or how to save them but no one is discussing which is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[preload= metadata](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp) shows a thumbnail automatically in browser, I would avoid complexity of storing the thumbnails all together, unless it is needed.

```
<video
    src="preSignedUrlCanGoHere"
    preload="metadata"
    controls
    controlsList="nodownload">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

For some platforms/browsers (for example, iOs Safari)

```
preload="metadata"
```

won't show you a thumbnail.
You can workaround it, by adding to src timestamp (#t=0.001):

```
<video
    src="preSignedUrlCanGoHere#t=0.001"
    preload="metadata"
    controls
    controlsList="nodownload">
</video>
```